# mint machine constantly stalling / freezing

Tags: linux-mint, freeze

I have an asus laptop with a hybrid drive running mint 18.3.
It constantly freezes (like dead frozen) for up to 4-5 seconds, and this happens every minute or so. I have no idea how to debug / diagnose what's happening here. `top` shows cinnamon spiking, but other than that there's nothing much happening.
Any idea where to start?

Comment: Did you read the system logs ?
(Type 'log' in the menu's search box)

Answer (score 0):

I used `18.3` without any problem. But in `19.2`, I had the same problem as you.

I thought it was something with Nvidia driver, but that did not help me anyway (different driver installed). I did an update of the kernel and now I have no problem anymore. Hope this helps you.